# Rich Snippet for website not working

Tags: seo, google-search, schema.org, google-rich-snippets

I am using this code to create an review rich snippet, with `$average` being the rating given by customers:

```
        echo '
        <span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
          <span itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
            <span itemprop="ratingValue">' . $average . '</span> /
            <span itemprop="bestRating">10</span>
          </span>
          <span itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
            <meta itemprop="name" content="Hentra autos">
          </span>
        </span>';
```

I used all the attributes (at least, I think), but the stars are not showing on Google. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it seems I can't use Rich Snippets for a rating on the whole website, only for ratings of products and that sorts of stuff.

Quality Score from Google AdWords is the thing for website, it seems.